# How to add a function to a specific toggler jQuery to show an additional div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

First off, I apologize in that I know very little of Javascript and even less of jQuery.

I have been able to use the solution jQuery found in another article to show/hide specific divs. What I am hoping to do is to add on to this function to piggyback an additional div.

Depending on the radio button selected, either "Individual" or "Joint" membership amounts are shown. What I would like to to is also show an additional div, "Joint Information", if the "Joint" radio button is selected. Due to the layout of the page, the two bits of relevant information are in separate divs separated by content not included in the function. (I'm working in 3rd party software and I can only pass a single "other" amount, so this seemed like a solution.)

I used this solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show();
    });
 });
```

The jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/DC4jz/

I'd really appreciate any help in clear, easy language. I'm not a programmer, nor do I play one on TV, but I do get to do my best for my non-profit and I love the depth of knowledge I find here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function(){
            $('.toHide').hide();
            $("#blk-"+$(this).val()).show();
        if($("#joint").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#JointInfo").show();
        } else {
            $("#JointInfo").hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/DC4jz/1/

Comment: Thank you!  This version makes a little more sense to me, and although I don't mind changing classes, it's helpful to see a solution using the taxonomy I used.

Comment: no problem, I wanted to give an answer that worked with what you had rather than changing the structure of your HTML. All the tools were already there so it made sense to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <div id="JointInfo" class="toHide" style="display:none">
```

to

```
 <div id="JointInfo" class="joint-info" style="display:none">
```

and then add the following line to the `$("[name=toggler]").click(function(){` function

```
    $('.joint-info').css("display", $(this).val() == "Joint" ? "" : "none");
```

Comment: Since the OP isn't skilled at JS, some explanation may be in order. According that what was posted, I doubt the OP knows what ternary operators are.

Comment: THANK YOU! I've spent four days on this, and you answered it in under 4 minutes. You rock.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Jeff. I can read the code and sort of parse out the logic of what's happening, but am completely incapable at this point of writing my own. aram90's answer allowed me to implement the fix, even though I really need to learn what I'm doing here. 

stackoverflow is awesome.